# Disable a specific USB port in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, usb, system

I need to disable a specific USB port programmatically on a Windows PC.

For example, let's say I have 2 removable disks plugged into my computer - one called F:\ and one called H:\ . I want to disable only F:\ programmatically.
I've already tried to use this CMD command to disable the device:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

and this one to enable the device:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "3" /f
```

But it does not work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want command or UI based solution ? UI based means you need to go to registry editor

Comment: A command nor code snippet would work best. Eventho UI based answer may help as well, because I can access Regedit programmatically. So I don't mind both of them :)

Comment: I have the same problem, I need to disable/enable only one usb port by commands but it looks noone knows... have you find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

Change value to 3

Comment: Uhm, read my question again please. I've already tried this exact command. Its not working. Changing the Value to 3, would only enable to storage device port, that's not what I'm looking for.